# Sharepoint search query web service results security trimming

Tags: sharepoint

I need to implement sharepoint search using query web service in javascript. I am able to do it but the results I am getting are not security trimmed. Users can see even those files which are not accessible to them (i.e. they dont have permission to view those files).
My questions are:

1. How to get security trimmed results when using query web service in javascript?
2. Is there any other way to perform search and get security trimmed results?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the query is being made from the users account/role (user is logged in and accesses a page with a query webpart, etc), that query should only return the security trimmed results. SharePoint's webservice handles the security trimming by default.

However,if you write a custom query and elevate privileges in your code, such as using the  SPSETUP account, then you will get non-user specific results. This is bad practice for the majority of scenarios.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working for me. I am using keyword query search. I have one file in document library which is accessible only by  userA and nobody else. But when I run my search query with other user's credentials, it displays this file in search results. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Has anybody faced this before?